# Conectar Base de datos AWS RDS mediante ESP32

Tags: php, mysql, arduino, aws

pongo en situación, estoy desarrollando en un ESP32 un pequeño código para recoger a partir de un DHT22 los datos de Temperatura y humedad. En su momento usaba una base de datos local con XAMP y MySQL para guardar los datos de temperatura y humedad y todo iba bien. Ahora he contratado Amazon Web Service (AWS) para alojar mis datos. El problema viene cuando en el código que me funcionaba antes con la base de datos local le cambio la dirección de mi ip local al endpoint de mi base de datos AWS RDS. Dejo aqui el codigo que he utilizado para esto:

```
#include <WiFi.h>
#include <WiFiClient.h>
#include <DHT.h>

#define DHTTYPE DHT22
#define DHTPIN 2

DHT dht(DHTPIN, DHTTYPE, 27);


//-------------------VARIABLES GLOBALES--------------------------
int contconexion = 0;

const char *ssid = "AQUI EL SSID DEL WIFI";
const char *password = "AQUI LA CONTRASEÑA DEL WIFI";

unsigned long previousMillis = 0;

int contdisconect;
double valuesdisconecttemperatura[999];
double valuesdisconecthumedad[999];

char host[48] = "";
String strhost = "AQUI EL ENDPOINT DE LA DB AWS RDS";
String strurl = "/enviardatos.php";

//-------Función para Enviar Datos a la Base de Datos SQL--------

String enviardatos(String datos) {
  String linea = "error";
  WiFiClient client;
  strhost.toCharArray(host, 49);
  if (client.connect(host, 80) != 1) {
    Serial.println(client.connect(host,80));
    Serial.println("Fallo de conexion");
    return linea;
  }
  Serial.println("hecho");
  client.print(String("POST ") + strurl + " HTTP/1.1" + "\r\n" +
               "Host: " + strhost + "\r\n" +
               "Accept: */*" + "*\r\n" +
               "Content-Length: " + datos.length() + "\r\n" +
               "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" + "\r\n" +
               "\r\n" + datos);
  delay(10);

  Serial.print("Enviando datos a SQL...");
  unsigned long timeout = millis();
  while (client.available() == 0) {
    if (millis() - timeout > 5000) {
      Serial.println("Cliente fuera de tiempo!");
      client.stop();
      return linea;
    }
  }

  // Lee todas las lineas que recibe del servidor y las imprime por la terminal serial
  while (client.available()) {
    linea = client.readStringUntil('\r');
  }
  Serial.println(linea);
  return linea;
}

//-------------------------------------------------------------------------
void conectarWiFi(){
    IPAddress ip(172, 20, 10, 7);
    IPAddress gateway(172, 20, 10, 1);
    IPAddress subnet(255, 255, 255, 240);
    WiFi.config(ip, gateway, subnet);
    Serial.println("");
    Serial.println("WiFi conectado");
    Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
}

void setup() {
  // Inicia Serial
  Serial.begin(115200);
  dht.begin();
  Serial.println("");
  // Conexión WIFI
  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED and contconexion < 50) { //Cuenta hasta 50 si no se puede conectar lo cancela
    ++contconexion;
    delay(500);
    Serial.print(".");
  }
  if (contconexion < 50) {
    //para usar con ip fija
    conectarWiFi();
  }
  else {
    Serial.println("");
    Serial.println("Error de conexion");
    }
  }


//--------------------------LOOP--------------------------------
void loop() {
    
    if(WiFi.status() == WL_CONNECTED){
    double HumedadActual =dht.readTemperature();
    double TemperaturaActual = dht.readHumidity();
    Serial.println(TemperaturaActual);
    Serial.println(HumedadActual);
    enviardatos("&HumedadActual=" + String(HumedadActual, 2) + "&TemperaturaActual=" + String(TemperaturaActual, 2));
    delay(2000);
    }
    else if(WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED){
      while(WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED){
      valuesdisconecttemperatura[contdisconect] = dht.readTemperature();
      valuesdisconecthumedad[contdisconect] = dht.readHumidity();
      contdisconect++;
      delay(5000);
      }
      conectarWiFi();
      for(int i=0;i <= contdisconect;i++){
        enviardatos("&HumedadActual=" + String(valuesdisconecthumedad[i], 2) + "&TemperaturaActual=" + String(valuesdisconecttemperatura[i], 2));
      }
      contdisconect=0;
  }
}
```

Además, como se puede observar en el código, utilizo un archivo PHP llamado enviardatos.php que es el siguiente:

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli('AQUI EL ENDPOINT DE AWS RDS', 'USUARIO DB', 'CONTRASEÑA DB', 'NOMBRE DB');
$mysqli->set_charset("utf8");

$Tiempo = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$TemperaturaActual = $_POST ['TemperaturaActual'];
$HumedadActual = $_POST ['HumedadActual'];

echo $TemperaturaActual;
echo $HumedadActual;

if ( $HumedadActual > 0){

$mysqli->query("INSERT INTO temperatura (SistemaCentral_idSistemaCentral, Tiempo, TemperaturaActual, HumedadActual) VALUES (1, '" . $Tiempo  . "' , '" . $TemperaturaActual . "', '" .  $HumedadActual . "')");

}

$mysqli->close();

echo "Datos ingresados correctamente.";
?>
```

También cabe destacar que he cambiado de lugar de trabajo y estoy utilizando ahora mi red móvil, no se si será un posible problema y afecte a los datos de la gateaway y subred.

Con todo esto, como he mencionado antes, al hacer el cambio únicamente de la dirección de mi base de datos local al endpoint de mi nueva base de datos en AWS RDS (este cambio se encuentra en la variable strhost del codigo) en el monitor serial me aparece lo siguiente:

```
 WiFi conectado

 172.20.10.7

 20.00

 15.00 
 
 0

 Fallo de conexión
```

y se vuelve a repetir esto cambiando únicamente los valores de temperatura y humedad que se muestran.

No encuentro solución a esto.

Comment: Por lo que entiendo, tu único problema es que no te puedes conectar con el servicio WEB (tu página PHP). Tu formulación de la pregunta confunde, y el código PHP que muestras no sirve para nada. Intenta conectar desde una máquina *normal* a tu PHP para descartar fallos debido a la red, o problemas de autorización de AWS.